# Writing a recommendation letter for a student I reported for academic dishonesty

Tags: recommendation-letter, cheating

A few years ago, I reported a student for academic dishonesty (in a graduate-level mathematics course, they were copying solutions off the internet, nearly verbatim). After acknowledging their wrong-doing with the Academic Integrity office on campus, they were allowed to drop the course.

The next year, the student re-enrolled in my course, and did reasonably well. I had no qualms about the originality of their work this time.

They recently asked me whether I would be willing to write them a recommendation letter for PhD programs in mathematics.

If I write a letter, am I obligated to write about the academic dishonesty incident? It appears to me that the student has already faced the consequences of their actions (they had to drop the course); however, this was a significant part of my interactions with the student and it seems dishonest to not mention it.

(I am aware that I could simply tell the student that I am not comfortable writing a letter, but I am curious to know what one should do in this situation if one did write a letter.)

Some facts: when the incident occured, the student was in their first semester of our masters program. They are also an international student, and this was their first semester in the US.

---

ETA: Look, I framed the question to be as general as possible so that it can be useful to the community as a whole. Since some commentors are choosing to attack my teaching practices, below are some more specifics, where once again I am trying to not reveal the identity of this student, myself, the course, the university, etc. I am actively trying to do what's best for the student here (note that I clearly state that I think the student has faced consequences for their actions; I am also not using my usual ac.se account to post this), and I don't understand where comments about "shutting down a student's career" are coming from.

I clearly state in my syllabus and on the first day of class that copying solutions off the internet (or any written source) is not allowed. I do this because I encountered this situation as a TA in graduate school. In particular, students are allowed to talk to anyone they like about problems, but I believe that when they just copy a solution, they are not learning. You are welcome to disagree with my policy, but it is my policy and my class, and it was clearly stated in two separate venues.

The copied solutions were virtually indistinguishable from the solutions online. This was not a matter of simply "being inspired". This was not isolated - three out of six solutions were copied, and those were just the ones I spotted. When I noticed this, I asked the student to come talk to me. I told them that I had noticed similarities between their work and solutions I had found online. I told them that I was not accusing them of anything, and they did not have to tell me anything; I reiterated that copying solutions from the internet was not permitted; I invited them to come to my office hours to talk about future problem sets; but that if I noticed such similarities again I would report them to Academic Integrity. They did it again on the next problem set (four out of six solutions).

Although they denied everything once via email, after talking with Academic Integrity (where they owned up to everything), they did find me and apologize. I was cordial to them throughout this event, and continued to be so afterward. We remain on good terms now. I consciously try to ensure that I do not let this incident color my interactions and behavior with them. They made a mistake once but people make mistakes and I am trying hard not to take it personally.

In summary, the incident itself was pretty blatant, the policy was clearly stated, and they had an opportunity to stop such that I would not have reported them if they had. I did not take reporting the student lightly. Nonetheless, I think academic dishonesty is a serious matter and it is our responsibility as faculty members to not turn a blind eye to it.

Comment: To clarify, the student was in a graduate-level course, but were they actually a graduate student?

Comment: @NateEldredge when the incident occured, the student was in their first semester of the masters program. They are also an international student.

Comment: Have you communicated with the AIO? I think it's important to check if the incident was permanently filed with the student's record. They may also give you some policy-based suggestions on this.

Comment: Have you asked the student how they'd discuss the academic dishonesty incident in the letter, if they were in your shoes? This will let student know that you haven't forgot about it, and it places some of the burden on the student about how to deal with a problem _they_ created.

Comment: Some countries have very lax cultures regarding plagiarism. The student probably had to learn to not do that at some point and apparently did so in your course. Do with that information as you may.

Comment: I agree with djechlin. If a student comes from a background in which such behavior is not understood as wrong then I would be wary of punishing to harshly. In my PhD, some students had answers to unpublished exams from previous years. Many of the questions were the same as current year exams. Yet, I would not have been happy reporting those students for academic dishonesty. After all, that material is "out there". This is the 21st century. Many students in your class more familiar with strict plagiarism rules could and likely did use online material and just masked the fact.

Comment: I think that such *detail* should be included in a letter of recommendation and of course explained that there were consequences for the student (i.e. already punished). Then it is up to the committee on the receiving end to decide whether they feel comfortable in having him aboard. There is this idea that cheating is common among overseas students. If that is true, I'm sure the committee will know about it and take it into account, and deal with it as they see fit. (Also, if instead of writing a letter one was on the receiving end, would you want to know about it?)

Comment: Seems that the student learned the lesson, isn't he ? And that's precisely what students should do. OK, he did wrong and was "punished", what you expect then ? to be marked with a red-hot iron for the rest of his life ? I will write the recommendation and not talk about the previous incident at all.

Comment: You have to also account for all the students copying homework that aren't caught. Sometimes this can be the majority of students. I wouldn't mention it unless it was a big project, an exam, or a bachelor/masters paper. You should ask yourself the question how honest your co-students where when you studied, or how the general climate is these days. Maybe they were caught because they're honest? If you never cheat you are quite bad at it, while some people have mastered the art and are never caught, but never do any work either and just learn for exams, slip by and forget everything immediatly.

Comment: Why do you feel so strongly about "copying solutions off the internet"? What about copying solutions off a book, off a fellow student? I guess everyone does research on the internet if they can not solve a problem, do you consider that unethical? Where do you draw the line between drawing inspiration and "copying a solution"? Did the student claim at any time that it was their original work or did they just hand in some exercises they found on the internet?

Comment: @Marcel the questions were exercises from the standard textbook in the subject (you should think Hatcher, or Lang, or Atiyah-Macdonald). These are questions that all graduate students should solve. I find it strange to be attacked for assigning such questions.

Comment: You know what they say, what is called collaboration in the workplace is called cheating in school.

Comment: @Marcel the premise that any time a student cheats the lectures or exercises are to blame is ridiculous.

Comment: I don't think I'd care if they copied solutions off the internet or anywhere else. I'd just re-structure my class so that test grades have a higher weight - if you're not practicing you're not learning and you won't get a good grade.

Comment: In grad school I was assigned to teach an independent study course where plagiarism was a frequent problem.  It was a course in technical writing in applied math.  The following semester, I scheduled a mandatory orientation session at the start of the semester, in which I showed the students examples of correct citation of someone else's work, and examples of incorrect use of someone else's work.  I made sure they understood what is plagiarism and what isn't. No plagiarism occurred that semester. I have to say, the department was very supportive of this approach.

Comment: Well, you just gave a short version of what happened the next year. From the sentence "the student re-enrolled in my course, and did reasonably well.", however, I think that he changed his approach, at least with your course. It is impossible to judge a person just by a small period, and much less by a few words on an online forum. Personally I'd just evaluate its most recent "performance" if you feel that he changed his approach. Maybe speaking to other teachers you can get a better idea on the student. And in the end,if you don't feel comfortable just be honest to him and tell what you think

Comment: @Anonymous_professor remember. This is the internet. While I am not at all being accusatory keep in mind that people who complain might've had bad experiences... or worse: chested themselves. I'm being completely neutral here. Just saying to take advice of that nature with a large grain of salt. However, if 90% of the class were reported for cheating... then I would start to wonder if someone wasn't making stuff up.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

TL; DR: The student probably wants you to write a letter to mitigate the harm of the incident because they already expect admissions committees to know about it. In that case, mention it briefly and move on to your standard letter.

---

There are only three reasons I can think of why a student would *ask* you to write a letter in this situation. How you respond depends on the reason.

1. **Despite, or perhaps because, of the incident you have become a mentor to the student and genuinely know the student very well.** The student knows that they have regained your trust and confidence, and that you're in a good position to give them a solid recommendation.

   - A. *If this is the case*, and you truly do now trust the student and want to offer a strong recommendation, you can mention that the two of you got off to a rocky start,  and allude to the issue without going into detail (you don't need to use the words "misconduct" or "cheating"). You could say that the student worked hard to regain your confidence, and that you are now happy to strongly recommend etc.
   - B. *If this is only sort of true*, and you don't think very highly of this student and/or have reason to think they might cheat again given the right circumstances, you should decline to write the letter.

It doesn't sound like your situation falls into the first category, however, which brings us to the second possibility.

2. **The student knows that this incident will appear on their record, and that their prospective programs *will* see it.** They believe they have at least somewhat redeemed themselves in your eyes, and are hoping that a generally positive letter from you will mitigate the harm of the incident. I suspect that this is what's actually going on. If so, you should confirm this. **Ask the student specifically whether the incident will already be known to admissions committees.**

   - A. *If the answer is **yes***, write whatever letter you would have written absent the misconduct but with an additional paragraph noting that you were involved in the incident and believe that the student has faced sufficient consequences, and that your letter focuses on their performance in the subsequent class. If you have reason to think the student has learned from the incident and it's not likely to be repeated, include that in the paragraph acknowledging the misconduct, but don't dwell on it.
   - B. *If the answer is **no***, the misconduct is sealed or otherwise unlikely to become know to prospective programs, we come to the third possibility.
3. **The student is extremely naive, and doesn't realize the potential harm you could do to their admissions chances by writing about the misconduct.**

   - A. In this case, absent any particularly strong admiration for the student, I would decline to write the letter. At the very least, you need to strongly caution the student about how bad a letter from you could be for them.
   - B. If you really still want to write the letter and your student still wants you to write it after being warned: You could take either approach above, depending on what feels more comfortable to you—either allude to the issue in the most general terms, or mention it but state specifically that it is not the focus of your letter. You should definitely warn your student about this beforehand, though, and perhaps allow them to see the letter before you send it.

Comment: As of my observation, many undergraduate programs in third world nation fail to warn their students about the negative impact of plagiarism. So they come to the grad school without realizing that plagiarism is never tolerated. The faculty should make sure that these rules (expectations regarding paraphrasing, referencing, and citing) are well communicated for the sake of these students.

I believe that it can be the scenario #3 you mentioned. The student seems to be underestimating her/his academic misconduct.

Comment: @PradeebanKathiravelu Yes, it certainly could be that; that's why it would be very important to verify the student's thought processes. It's also possible that it's something between 2 and 3—the student thinks the incident is obvious in their record, but it actually isn't—or between 1 and 3—the student thinks they've impressed the professor more than they have *and* that the incident had/will have less impact than it actually did/will have.

Comment: This is a really good answer. Any answer which doesn't take into account this highly disparate sets of circumstances will not give useful advice.

Answer (score 149):

The best option is:  Don't write the letter.  In a case like this, I would outright refuse to provide a recommendation.

However, if you are not comfortable with a non-negotiable refusal, you might want to simply tell the student that you cannot provide a positive letter for them.  If the student insists, then you should write an honest letter that gives a balanced evaluation of their ability and personal traits.  The fact that you caught the student cheating is a critically important piece of information in this regard, and it needs to be included. The cheating will almost certainly be the most salient feature to anyone who reads the letter, which will make the net effect of the letter, regardless of whatever else you say in it, strongly negative.  And if the student insists on you writing the letter in this situation, that is basically what they deserve.

Comment: Yes and a critical issue is that they were a graduate student.  If it had been a freshman cheating, you could chalk it up to immaturity and a lack of understanding of the gravity of what they were doing.  As @Buzz said, you shouldn't write the letter.  They may have learned, but at that point they should have known.  Integrity is a big deal in academia and any entering graduate student should have known better.

Comment: @user25459:  Yes, that's another important point.

Comment: @user25459 note that the student is from overseas, so it's quite possible they are from a country where academic integrity is less valued and emphasized than (say) the US or Western Europe, which I think would completely invalidate your point.

Comment: @DanRomik - I've heard versions of "overseas students don't know about cheating" for the last twenty years and I call bullshit on it. 1) They should know; 2) They should know it has consequences; and 3) There should be real consequences.

Comment: @RoboKaren well, from my personal experience serving for two years on my university's Campus Judicial Bkard, during which time I participated in many academic misconduct hearings, I can attest that there was a suspiciously high percentage of overseas students (from certain particular countries). Moreover, those students were also the ones who made some of the most absurd and laughable arguments in their own defense. This is anecdotal of course, but It is consistent with observations by many other people. Why deny that this is a real phenomenon? I do agree with your assertion number 3 though.

Comment: I don't deny that it's a phenomenon but I think it's a handy excuse both for the perpetrators and those who want to defend the perpetrators. I think the only way we can solve this is by disallowing this as an excuse and making sure that there are consequences.

Comment: By the way I don't mean to suggest that overseas students should be treated with any more lenience than other students. Simply, it should be acknowledged that there are cultural differences at play, and this fact was relevant in the context of the comment made by @user25459. So yes, I completely agree with you it's not an excuse.

Comment: @DanRomik I live "overseas". Academic dishonesty is a very popular way of advancing your career even as a senior researcher around here. They know exactly what they are doing and why. It's just that in my country they don't get punished. Then they end up as PhD advisers and ask their students for money and paintings (I kid you not). They also end up in all sorts of scientific committees and decide only their friends should be awarded grant money. And it all started with a dash of well meant leniency.

Comment: @Magicsowon once again, **I am not advocating for any leniency based on geographical origins**. I was simply making a point about user24549's point being potentially invalid. The student _should_ face consequences for cheating, and by all accounts has in fact done so. It doesn't mean the consequences should be career-killing ones.

Comment: I don't excuse it on cultural grounds, but I can't claim some kind of superiority for Western culture.  In 2004, I found online five copies of a pretty good essay on philosophies of education.  All five were on professor's websites with NO attribution, giving the impression that it had been written by the professor running the website.

Comment: "cheating will almost certainly be the most salient feature to anyone who reads the letter" is a pretty broad (imo wrong) statement. Letters of Rec aren't going to be read until at least one or two good cuts of the application pool based on things like program of origin and GPA/tests. At that point my feeling is most admissions committees are looking for reasons to include people in the program rather than exclude. Nobody has a perfect academic record- cheating is certainly a serious offense but does not make someone a pariah.

Comment: @Magicsowon By “overseas”, do you mean the US or Europe? I’m asking because it depends on where you currently are. And surely you’re not implying that “Western” scientific culture is somehow inherently more honest than the rest …?

Comment: @Magicsowon I studied at a US university, and there it was considered cheating if I spotted someone else (next to me or halfway accross the room) cheat and NOT report it. I actually got in trouble because a TA overheard a conversation I had with a friend about it, and I did not want to denounce the culprit (I simply acted as if I did not remember who it was). Where I come from, this is NOT cheating.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I live in Eastern Europe. But I also worked in US and Western Europe and there is (significantly) less academic dishonesty there. Whether is inherent to the scientific culture, or not, I don't believe I can explain in this text box.

Comment: Eh..."You break the law, its there for people to see, why should you get the same as an honest man like me..."

Comment: @solalito That is pretty extreme. Im also in the US and while I didnt get in trouble the professor was a little irritated when I mentioned the person sitting two or three rows away was disruptively cheating to the point that it was impossible to ignore, and while they didnt get mad they did seem kind of taken surprised. Perhaps they already noticed, but it gave the impression you dont have to actively watch for/report it. Are you sure the TA wasnt being rude? Sure he/she didnt lie cause you made them mad? TAs are usually just fellow students. They couldve just had something against you.

Comment: Granted, in the same respect, actively watching for someone cheating is not the same as just ignoring it. Still though. That seems weird that you would be punished. The TA seems weird for even assuming you know who cheated and didnt just notice it...

Comment: @TheGreatDuck The TA may have just been in-experienced and a bit over-zealous in his attempts to stop cheating rather than rude. As - at least it seemed so to me - so much of your work as a TA has become making sure source code and other work isn't plagiarized, especially when student submissions use your own code from Github account or an answer on SO, that you may overreact when confronting it. I'm pretty sure during my early graduate years I snapped at an undergrad or two not due to anger at them but just because I was sick of cheating in general and in-experienced.

Comment: @JGreenwell oops. I thought you meant SI.

Comment: @RoboKaren: "@DanRomik - I've heard versions of 'overseas students don't know about cheating' for the last twenty years and I call bullshit on it." - I definitely see certain limits when it comes to e.g. handing in someone else's text when one's personal writing skills are supposed to be tested (because that clearly undermines the purpose), but certain views and assumptions can indeed differ by culture - even within the so-called Western world: On this site, I learned about the idea that sometimes, looking at previous exam questions is apperently considered cheating in the U.S. and ...

Comment: ... students should rather ask the instructor for permission first. From my German perspective, that sounds quite incredible as students here are normally *expected* to actively collect any information they can get about previous exams as a part of their normal preparation that goes without saying.

Comment: @user21264 surely overseas is not a single place

Answer (score 66):

**To what extent has the student regained your trust since the incident?**

As other answers say, the incident is too significant to ignore.  However, what you write in the letter should be not just “X happened”, but “X happened, and here’s how it affects my judgement of the student now.”

Most probably, your trust in their future honesty is still shaken, in which case (if you’re honest about this) your letter *will* carry a significant negative impact, to the extent that you should probably decline the request.

However, there could be mitigating circumstances that make you genuinely confident that the student will not re-offend.  For instance — since you mention they were a newly-arrived international student — perhaps their home country had a different culture around expectations for homework, but you feel confident that they have now absorbed US academic norms.  In that case you can say so in the letter:

> I would be remiss not to mention that [incident occurred].  However, I feel this should not be held against X’s future prospects, since [mitigating circumstances, and why you feel they’ve regained your trust].

I would expect, for most readers, this would still have *some* negative effect on their assessment of the student — but much less than if they learned of the incident some other way (e.g. mentioned on the student’s academic transcript) without an explanation of the mitigating factors.  So overall, submitting this letter would be a positive thing (provided that the rest of it is enthusiastic).

Disclaimer: I have only a little experience of admissions/hiring; I hope more experienced users can confirm (or differ with) my expectation of how such a letter will be received.

Comment: In the same situation, I would be wondering whether the student has learned that the behavior was inappropriate, or whether he has merely learned that you don't get away with it in a university in this country.

Comment: @immibis I think GregMartin just means that the sentence should have "or whether _they_ have merely learned", i.e. agrees with you and thinks gender shouldn't be there.  I think you may have mis-read the intent of the comment.  Unless I have!

Comment: @MichaelDurrant There may be a (completely inconsequential) bias towards using the pronoun "he", but since the student's gender makes no impact whatsoever, I wouldn't imply that the answer is biased because of it.

Comment: I disagree, and so does research into the matter, e.g., http://www.apaonline.org/?page=nonsexist and https://web.stanford.edu/class/linguist156/Gastil_1990.pdf

Comment: @Kat: as you say, there's a long tradition of using “he” as a generic pronoun. However, as Gerg’s links show, that usage isn't unconnected from the sexist biases we all unconsciously hold. (For one thing, I've heard people invoke that to defend their use of “he” for a generic mathematician, but then as soon as they have cause to talk about a generic secretary, suddenly they use “she” .)  So I wouldn't take anyone's use of “he” to indicate a deliberate gender assumption — but it is nonetheless a small piece of sexism that I think is worth trying to avoid.

Comment: Gender pronouns aside, the takeaway from PLL's answer is that the professor has 3 gambles to choose from: (A) Include the incident in the letter, but justify the student's progress and hope that the reviewers are equally forgiving; (B) Write the letter *without* the incident, and risk that the reviewers won't discover this information without the context of the student's improvement; or (C) Don't write the letter, and leave the student's fate to factors outside of the professor's control.  My first choice would be C, second choice would be A.

Comment: I don't understand where this idea of "cheating is their culture" is coming from. Academic dishonesty is academic dishonesty. People get kicked out of school for it all over the world. The student's honesty or lack thereof should be judged on its own merits, and based on their individual interactions with the professor, not on some patronizing assessment of substandard ethics overseas.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin: going on my own first-hand experience in N America and Europe, the following all definitely vary widely between institutions and countries/regions: (a) the prevalence of cheating; (b) the severity of penalties for cheating; (c) the perceived moral severity of cheating; (d) the relative severity of cheating on homework vs. on exams; (e) the threshold of what counts as cheating.  So, when people with first-hand experience have told me that these vary even more in other parts of the world, I’ve found that very plausible.  Comments on other answers include some specific examples.

Answer (score 33):

I do not think that you have to mention the incident and that you may well choose to not include it. What you do should mostly depend on what you think of the student *now* as the recommendation letter is used to estimate how the student *will perform in the future* and not to assess how they had performed in all previous life.

If you have reason to believe that the student learned their lesson from the incident and you think that you can recommend them, then I see two options:

- You start from the assumption that the incident should not be something that should haunt the student forever and you just do not mention it. This is in line with your saying that "the student has already faced the consequences of their actions". Also, it's based on the view that the student should not be penalized twice for the exact same event. Also, copying solutions from the web verbatim does not appear to me as something which is so genuinely dishonest that the student should carry the weight of that incident forever.
- You include the incident in the letter but add that the student has performed well in the class and no other dishonesty has appeared so far.

Comment: If an incident of failed integrity is known, and the choice is made to not include it in the letter, does that not equate to failed ethical integrity on the part of the letter writer?

Comment: @NZKshatriya: Only if you believe the letter writer has an ethical obligation to include it.  Dirk apparently thinks they do not.

Comment: Maybe the "if you have reason to believe..." part should be emphasized more.

Comment: @NZKshatriya good question. You pose it as a rhetorical question but the answer seems far from obvious to me. For example, I stole a candy from a store when I was a kid. Does that mean that every person writing me an LOR in the future after reading this comment should be required to mention this "incident of failed integrity" or be tainted by a similar failed integrity themselves?

Comment: @DanRomik Well, as far as academic integrity goes, everyone's view on how far back to track transgressions is different.   Stealing candy, and cheating in a class, at least to me....seems a bit odd of a comparison.

Comment: @NZKshatriya exactly, your last comment reinforces my point: if as you say "everyone's view on how far back to track transgressions is different", then a choice not to mention a cheating incident from a few years ago is entirely reasonable. Hence your sweeping statement (expressed as a rhetorical question) about failed integrity being automatically transmittable through an LOR-writing relationship is overly general and simplistic.

Answer (score 26):

I found myself in this very same situation several years ago and informed the student I would not be able to write a letter without mentioning the incident that brought them before the AIO. The student insisted, and so I wrote an honest letter of recommendation, which included an account of the incident. The student wasn't accepted into the program they had applied to do their PhD (she was eventually accepted into another program that I had not written a letter for), and a year later, a professor from the first program who received the letter complained to one of my colleagues; claiming I should have recused myself despite my having stated in the letter that the student had insisted I write one. I would have thought the program the student applied to would appreciate an honest review, but that isn't always the case. Lesson learned - don't write a letter of recommendation unless you have nothing but good things to say about the student.

Comment: I disagree with the complaining prof but appreciate the first-hand insight; +1

Comment: "The student wasn't accepted into the program they had applied to do their PhD (she was eventually accepted into another program that I had not written a letter for), and a year later, a professor from the first program who received the letter complained to one of my colleagues; claiming I should have recused myself despite my having stated in the letter that the student had insisted I write one." You got a complaint about a letter in which you were honest in your reporting of relevant information?  That sucks.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark What injury was done to the complaining professor, I wonder?

Comment: "I would have thought the program the student applied to would appreciate an honest review" - it sounds like you essentially dis-recommended the student with your honest review, which is why that Professor complained.

Comment: Yes, no doubt my letter was instrumental in the decision to reject her. What I failed to mention in my first post was that I only spoke of the one incident because it was the only one that resulted in a sanction.

Comment: +1 as this answer gives direct indication of how readers of such a letter reacted.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The complaining professor was disappointed to waste time on an not recommended student. Without this honest review (which is not the same as a recommendation letter), the student would not have applied, or it would have applied using a real recommendation letter. In the first case, no time is wasted, in the second case, the committee would have had the chance to know what *recommends* this student, which they couldn't find out from the *honest review*.

Answer (score 23):

First of all, from an ethical point of view I don't think you have an obligation to report the incident. Mentioning it would likely destroy the student's chances of getting into a good PhD program, so if your philosophical view about crime and punishment is that a single incident of cheating does not prove that someone is irredeemably morally corrupt, and specifically think that there's a fair chance that this particular student learned their lesson and will not repeat the offense, it's reasonable not to mention it.

Second, I can suggest the following course of action that would make it possible for you to get to a more comfortable place about the decision to write a letter for the student. Invite the student for a chat, and explain to them that you think they're a good student with potential to succeed in a graduate program, but that you have a dilemma about whether to write the letter because of the cheating incident. Ask them to tell you their view about the incident - why they did it, how they feel about it now etc. I think the student's answer is likely to be quite revealing and either make you more sympathetic to their situation and more comfortable writing the letter, or make you realize that they probably didn't learn their lesson and that you should not write the letter after all. In any case it will allow you to reach a more informed decision that you are more at peace with.

Comment: Not that I disagree with you, but your first paragraph seems to indicate there is a problem with ideal reality _somewhere_.  If the incident should disqualify the student from good PhD programs, then not mentioning it is somehow dishonest.  If it shouldn't, then mentioning it shouldn't _destroy the student's chances_.

Comment: @Kimball you are spot on, indeed there is a very real "problem with ideal reality": in an ideal world, mentioning an incident of cheating shouldn't _necessarily_ destroy a student's chance of getting into a PhD program, but in the real world it almost certainly will. This is precisely why there is an ethical dilemma here, since it puts two values (the professor's wish to make the LOR as honest as possible on the one hand, and their wish to do the thing that results in the most just outcome on the other hand) in direct conflict with each other.

Comment: @Kimball: I don't know enough about letters of recommendation for academic programs (we basically don't have them in my country) but over here letters of recommendation written by employers are highly codified in their phrases and only give positive sides (the analogue for the present question would maybe a phrase *missing* that states OP has always known the student to be acting strictly honestly). Likewise, I suspect that how things should be ideally is less of a concern than adhering to (unwritten) rules of whether and how to state what in this situation.

Comment: @cbeleites A lot of academics write letters in a similar way, but your suggested analogue doesn't make sense here because professors wouldn't normally write something like "this person has never cheated" as it's taken for granted.  Another issue that the community is small, and if your letters are not honest people will realize this and start ignoring them.

Comment: @Kimball: another difference is that the employer cannot refuse to write such a letter, while the academic can. And I suspect (also from reading the other answers and comments) that this is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 16):

Interesting question!

Seeing as you are *even entertaining the possibility* of writing a letter, you might want to check it up with the student, to inquire about his/her point of view in coming to ask you (despite your troublesome history) for a recommendation letter. It should be as clear to him/her that you would be **at least** partially split on the matter.

Maybe the student considers facing the consequences of a wrong-doing and mending the bridges to be an important lesson, maybe that's the theme the student is going for... I don't know, I am purely speculating here. It's equally possible that the student thinks that what's done is done and now forgotten. Obviously the two alternative scenarios do not warrant the same type of response.

But by engaging in a dialogue, you might gain insight as to how the student in question thinks, and thereby make a more informed decision.

Comment: However, I think that while the student's view is important information in judging whether they learned their lesson or not, it is even more important for the letter to adhere to the (probably unwritten) rules for letters of recommendation. Otherwise the message read may differ a lot from the intended message of the writer.

Answer (score 8):

"If you can't say something good about someone, say nothing at all." This is a letter that you obviously don't want to write. Tell the student that you are simply unable to write a letter that would be acceptable to both of you. Then simply move on.

Comment: While I entirely agree with your opinion, your answer does not answer the question. @Anonymous_professor asks if it would be unethical to not include the incident in a recommendation letter, once he decided to write a recommendation letter. So, the letter is happening for sure, not writing it is not an option at this point.

Answer (score 8):

I do not think it's appropriate for anyone to suffer the consequence of a single misconduct twice. Hence, I would rather you decline the student's request to write the letter or pen down something good about him if you do decide to oblige him.

Answer (score 5):

I have to admit that I agree with everyone but Buzz and Inde.

The AnonProf should

1. Talk to the student. (I would have done this the moment he/she approached for a recommendation.)
2. Warn the student that the recommendation might include this incident (including any positive outcomes), but maybe not.
3. AnonProf needs to search his/her own soul about *"crime and punishment"* or *"infraction and redemption"* and how he/she feels about the student's rehabilitation,
4. and, **independently of the incident**, AnonProf needs to search his/her own *head* about this student's performance in *mathematics*.
5. Then AnonProf needs to decide whether or not the cosmos would be better off writing the letter or not.  That is not synonymous with whether or not the student would be better off or if the academe or the mathematics profession would be better of, but may be very closely related to that.

Comment: I'd like to add that AnonProf (even more than they already do with this question) need to find out the local (country specific) "code" or "etiquette" for letters of recommendation in such awkward situations. Which I guess may very well turn out to be "refuse to write one".

Comment: I like this answer. Personally I'd have put point #4 as point #1. Can AnonProf say that he is now convinced that the student is a *gifted* mathematician, or not? In other words, has he interacted with the student in an environment such as tutorials where cheating was quite impossible, and found the student's mathematical abilities on a par with, or even superior to, his own?

Answer (score 4):

**An in-between option**

Write the letter as you normally would, and mention that you had a *disciplinary incident* with the student, without details. This would most likely give them the possibility to explain themselves to the addressee of the letter, and if the latter chooses to contact you for details, you would naturally explain what happened from your point of view.

You could say for example, "The student took my course X and dropped out due to a disciplinary incident, then in the next year took it again and I saw them to be this and that"

Answer (score 4):

I would consider showing the student a draft of the letter and seeing if the student wanted me to submit it.

I generally assume that even if a student waives the right to see the letter, there is still the possibility that he or she will see it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Only write the LoR if you are confident that the student learned from the incident and if you are fine letting it go. If you are not able to write the letter without mentioning the incident, then avoid writing it altogether.

Including it in the letter could jeopardize two things: your integrity as an educator and the student's future hireability. **If the institution and the student and yourself have all come to an accord, no need to hang the student out to dry by opening him to questions by a future employer.** Additionally, if this student goes on to perform poorly or in some way cast a poor reputation on whatever company hires him, then future students from your institution may be viewed from a deficit. Lastly, a letter of recommendation from you would be suspect to further scrutiny.

Commit to abstaining or supporting the student. That's a call only you can make given what you know about him/her.

Comment: _cast a poor reputation on whatever **company** hires him_? A kind reminder, the OP's student is asking the OP _to write them a recommendation letter for **PhD programs in mathematics**_

Comment: Ahh, I seem to have overlooked that, my apologies. Regardless of what institution/entity is applying to, I feel the same principles of reputation still apply in some manner.

Answer (score -1):

It is not unethical, if you do not mention the incident. Of course, this is under the obvious assumption that you truly recommend the student for the PhD position, since you decided to write a recommendation letter.

Moreover, I consider it **unethical** to include negative comments in a *recommendation* letter. My reasoning for this is that a recommendation letter is just that, a *recommendation* letter. If one's not recommending in a *recommendation* letter, one is not writing a *recommendation* letter, but just a letter, and one is failing to uphold the agreement that it made with the student to *recommend* him through a *recommendation* letter.

A recommendation letter should only include why you recommend someone, the fact that you recommend that person is already clear from the existence of the recommendation letter.

A recommendation letter is **NOT**:

- a summary report on previous activity of the student
- a letter in which one gossips random unrequested facts about a student

The moment one includes *not recommending* comments in a *recommendation* letter, you start being [deceptive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deceptive) (by definition):

- towards the person that you are recommending, by giving false hopes
- towards the committee to which the letter is addressed, by recommending (hence the existing of the letter) someone you do not believe it should be recommended, since you include damaging aspects

Breaking an agreement and being deceptive is not ethical.

In conclusion, not only that not including the damaging story would be ethical, but the reverse, i.e. including the damaging story, is definitively unethical.